# Centralize a button click event in a jquery file

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a jquery files `xyz.js`.

I have a anchor tag click event that is used almost in every view.
How can i call that event in the centralize file?

Comment: $('#filePrivilege').click(function () {
        //code here
    });
where filePrivilege is the id of anchor tag.
placed this code in xyz.js

Comment: you could set the onlick of the tags to that method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your anchor is going to appear more than once on a page, you will want to use a class.  You can hook up the click event to your anchor as follows:

Html:

```
<a class="ClassNameHere">...</a>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(function(){

  $('a.ClassNameHere').click(someFunctionToExecute);
});
```

Comment: I have a class name as "inline UpdateLink" how can i bind event to that?

Comment: There are two class names there, I'm assuming the one you would want to use is UpdateLink... so $('.UpdateLink').click(someFunctionToExecute);